# In Linq search a list using items in another list

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, comparison

I have a list of roles that a user has

```
List<Role> userRoles; // this is a list of roles
```

Then I have Folders which have one or more associated roles and can be accessed Folders.Roles.

I want to return a list of folders that match a field in the folders and also have a role in the child roles list that is in the userRoles list.

I can do basically what I want using some foreach statements ...

```
bool hasRole = false;
            List<Folder> folders2 = _customerPortalDbContext.Folders.Where(f => f.ParentFolderId == Guid.Empty).ToList();
            foreach(Folder f in folders2)
            {
                foreach (Role role in f.Roles)
                {
                  if(  roles.Any(r => r.Id == role.Id)) hasRole = true;
                }
            }
```

But I feel I have seen or done similar in the past using some clever Linq code so hoping this may be possible? Something like

```
IQueryable<Folder> folders = _customerPortalDbContext.Folders.Where(f => f.FolderType == "FolderType") 
&& f.Roles.RoleId.<<Compare to roles in List of roles>>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got classes like this :

```
    class Folder
    {
        public Guid ParentFolderId { get; set; }
        public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }

    class Role
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

And your two lists :

```
List<Folder> folders2
List<Role> userRoles = new List<Role>();
```

I think, you could try something like this :

```
bool hasRole = folders2
    .Where(f=>f.ParentFolderId == Guid.Empty) // only gets folders with no parent
    .SelectMany(f => f.Roles) // gets all roles from all folders
    .Any(r => userRoles.Any(ur => ur.Id == r.Id)); // checks if userRoles contains a role with the same Id
```

I think you could also use Contains instead of Any if you override the Equals methods in you Role class. That could improve the readability but you need to be careful because it would override it for every comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of IDs and use `Contains`:

```
idList = userRoles.Select(r => r.Id).ToList();

IQueryable<Folder> folders = _customerPortalDbContext.Folders
    .Where(f => f.FolderType == "FolderType" 
             && f.Roles.Any(r => idList.Contains(r.RoleId)));
```

`Contains` will translate to an `IS IN` SQL expression, using your ID list as a set of constant values.